# Machine in read-only mode, do I really need to restart?

Tags: linux, centos, vmware-esx, storage-area-network

In a combination of SAN controller failover and loss of power, several of our machines ended up in read-only mode. After restoring from the failover, I restarted all machines. This got me thinking if it was really necessary.

How can/sho I recover a machine from being in read-only?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Read Only?

Comment: He means that the kernels in the VMs remounted their local filesystems read-only when the backend storage was unavailable for a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rebooting is the best thing to do.  When the backend storage failed, the filesystems may have been left in an inconsistent state, just as if you'd pulled the plug on a bare-metal server.  Furthermore any running services may have aborted because all of a sudden they were unable to write to disk.

You *could* try remounting filesystems read-write, e.g.

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

and restarting services, but it's much safer to reboot the VMs, let them do their `fsck`ing, and let the services recover cleanly.

Comment: Yup. I would rather reboot than have to wonder if my filesystems are consistent. On my VMware clusters a VM reboot takes something like 30 secs so it's not even a hassle.